# In the CMAKE UI what is the parameter name to specify where header files get written to

Tags: path, cmake, header-files

I am building a project, using the CMAKE UI (2.8-10.app) and would like to know where I specify where the system header files of the project should be written to.

I see 'LIBRARY_OUTPUT_PATH' - and I see that my libraries get written here.

However, I am unable to find an equivalent 'HEADERFILE_OUTPUT_PATH'

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Headers don't normally get produced as part of the build process.  Can you explain a bit more what you mean?

Comment: Maybe you could use the [install command](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.10/cmake.html#command:install).